# Should Consistency or Semantics be valued more in terms of language?

Tags: consistency, semantics

In my application, there are several pages where the user can edit data or create a new entry all together. The main header of each page gives a brief description of the action the user is performing, such as "Creating Entry" or "Editing Entry".

However there are some cases where it feels more appropriate to title the page "Adding ..." instead of "Creating ...".

Would this take away from user experience in terms of consistent language across the application? Is this a complete non issue that I am over analyzing?

I don't want to confuse the user by using different terms for similar actions, but I also feel the semantics in this case is important.

I hope some of you can shed some light on this dilemma, thanks!

Comment: Whats the difference between "adding" and "creating" regarding process / type of entry?

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose, and in your case I will use **Add**. It's not recommended to use different words.

Meaning of create: bring (something) into existence.

Meaning of add: join (something) to something else so as to increase the size, number, or amount.

If you use "create", you will do it with no problem, but when you create another one, probably its not the best word. When you use "add" you will **add something to your entire system, anything**, and it will do the next time you use this option.

You could use **New** too without problems.